# Use of Streams,Enumerator and Websockets in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I'm looking for the proper way to use play's Enumerator (play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[A]) in my code, i have a stream of object of type "InfoBlock" and i want to redirect it to a websocket.What i actually do is:

The data structure holding the blocks

> private lazy val buf:mutable.Queue[InfoBlock] = new mutable.SynchronizedQueue[InfoBlock]

The callback to be used in the Enumerator

```
def getCallback: Future[Option[InfoBlock]] = Future{

if (!buf.isEmpty)
  Some(buf.dequeue)
else
  None}
```

Block are produced by another thread and added to the queue using:

```
buf += new InfoBlock(...)
```

Then in the controller i want to set up a websocket to stream that data,doing:

```
def stream = WebSocket.using[String]{ request =>

  val in = Iteratee.consume[String]()

  val enu:Enumerator[InfoBlock] = Enumerator.fromCallback1(
   isFirst => extractor.getCallback
  )

  val out:Enumerator[String] = enu &> Enumeratee.map(blk => blk.author+"  ->  "+blk.msg)

(in,out)}
```

It works but with a big problem, when a connection is open it sends a bunch of blocks (=~ 50) and stops, if i open a new websocket then i get another bunch of blocks but no more.I tried to set some property to the js object WebSocket in particular i tried setting

```
 websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"
```

because i thought using "blob" may be the cause but i was wrong the problem must be server side and i have no clue..

Answer (score 0):

From the Enumerator ScalaDocs on Enumerator.fromCallback, describing the retriever function:

> The input function.  Returns a future eventually redeemed with Some value if there is input to pass, or a future eventually redeemed with None if the end of the stream has been reached.

This means that the enumerator will start by pulling everything off the queue. When it is empty, the callback will return a None. The enumerator sees this as the end of the stream, and closes sends a Done state downstream. It won't be looking for any more data

Rather than using a mutable queue for message passing, try and push the Enumerator/Iteratee paradigm into your worker. Create an Enumerator that outputs instances of the what you're creating, and have the iteratee pull from that instead. You can stick some enumerates in the middle to do some transforms if you need to.

Comment: You got right into the problem, but is not very clear to me how to push the iteratee/enumerator paradigm down to my worker since the Enumerator constructor has to deal with some data structure so i can create it with either an InputStream or a collection but both will be handled outside the Enumerator